# To construct a graph with desired eccentricity.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am trying to solve a problem.

$G$ is a graph where eccentricity of vertices $x$ and $y$ is $8$,
and rest of the vertices have eccentricity $7$. Also $d(x,y) = 8$. I am trying to make eccentricities of $x$ and $y$ also $7$ by adding a vertex (or two vertices). ***The old graph must be induced in new graph***. I proposed a construction:

> Let $w$ be any vertex in $G$ such that $d(y,w) = 3$. Add a new vertex $z$ and make it adjacent to $y$ and $w$.

Is this true that every vertex in this new graph will have eccentricity $7$? For a few examples, I got the desired result. Or is there any other way to construct this(by adding one more vertex)?

PS: As asked by @bof, I tried for a smaller value. Like in the following figure, two vertices have eccentricity three and rest have eccentricity two, I tried to make eccentricity of every as two by adding a new vertex. **As required the old graph is induced in new graph.**

[image]

Comment: The eccentricity of a graph vertex in a connected graph is the maximum graph distance between and any other vertex of.

Comment: I have a definition of eccentricity only on trees, what is the definition on graphs, for example if I have $K_4$ how eccentricity of each vertex?

Comment: Since for an arbitrary vertex $x$  in $K_4$, the maximum distance between $x$ and other vertices is one, hence eccentricity is one for every vertex of $K_4$ and hence for every complete graph. See this link will help you. :)  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/graph_theory/graph_theory_basic_properties.htm

Comment: Are you sure this can be done? Was this given as an exercise?

Comment: Yeah, it is an exercise. Prove or disprove type.

Comment: Re "*Also $d(x,y)=8$*", you could replace "*Also*" with "*It is easy to prove that*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessarily true that the eccentricity of every vertex in the new graph is exactly $7$.

In the graph below, the eccentricity of $z$ is $6$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing a counter example. It was a headache to disprove. :) So, is there any other way of constructing such graph?

Comment: @monalisa I'll try to think about it, but it seems quite difficult to find a way to make the eccentricity of each vertex **exactly** $7$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts. I appreciate it.